# AJAX Node.js form 404 error. Problem with route?

Tags: node.js, ajax, forms

I'm using AJAX and Node.js together for the first time and I don't know why I'm getting a 404 error. I suspect it's something to do with the route, which I tried to change, but it didn't work. Any hints?

server code:

```
const express = require ("express")
const path = require ("path")
const nodemailer = require ("nodemailer")

const { check , validationResult} = require('express-validator')

const app = express ();

app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "/")));

app.post ("http://projetocc.learningtodom.com/ajax", [
   check('name')
   .not().isEmpty(), 
   check('email', 'Favor Preencher E-mail Corretamente')
   .not().isEmpty().isEmail()

], function(request, response){
   const  errors = validationResult(request);
```

form code

```
 <div class="container">
        <div id="form">
          <h1 class="page-title">Quer Ser Nosso Cliente? Preencha o Questionário Abaixo</h1>

          <form id="form-user" method="POST" action="http://projetocc.learningtodom.com/ajax" onsubmit="return submitEmailForm(form);">

            <div>
              <ul class="error">
```

Hints?

Answer (score 1):

Your route should not contain your Sever name, It should be as follows

```
app.post ("/ajax", [
```

Comment: I changed it and it still didn't work. Should I change the action on the form as well?